# Aptana formatter - Never join already wrapped lines

Tags: javascript, aptana, formatter

Eclipse Java formatter has "Never join already wrapped lines" configuration option.

Is there any similar option in Aptana for javascript?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

No such setting in the JS formatter yet. 
You can open a ticket at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs and we'll see what can be done.
When you open that ticket, please provide some samples for the way you want it to work.

Cheers